# I need a word in English that means "from complexity to singularity" or "from complexity to simplicity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, phrases, american-english, phrase-meaning

I'm looking for either a word or a phrase meaning "from many to one" or "from complexity to singularity".

Comment: How about *simplification*?

Comment: _E Pluribus Unum_, or alternatively, _dumbing down_. Depending on context.

Comment: Usually when posting for "Single Word Requests", we ask for a sample sentence showing how the word is to be used. i.e. part of speech, etc

Comment: These seem like two different situations. There are some words that work for your first case (amalgamation, synthesis, combination) that don't work at all for the second case, and vice versa (e.g. simplification, resolution for your second case). Please clarify your question, or possibly split it into two questions if needed. Examples sentences are key.

Comment: I voted to close.  There are just too many possibilities without context and sample sentence (e.g. integrate, incorporate, braid, prune, and on and on).

Answer (score 1):

Consider :

Reductionism :

An attempt or tendency to explain a complex set of facts, entities, phenomena, or structures by another, simpler set: 
"Science requires some degree of reductionism, some picking apart and focusing on one or two variables at a time" (Natalie Angier).

OR :

Ockham's razor
n.
A rule in science and philosophy stating that entities should not be multiplied needlessly. 
This rule is interpreted to mean that the simplest of two or more competing theories is preferable 
and that an explanation for unknown phenomena should first be attempted  in terms of what is already known. Also called law of parsimony.

(Philosophy) a maxim, attributed to William of Ockham,
 stating that in explaining something assumptions
 must not be needlessly multiplied. Also called: the principle of economy

Answer (score 0):

Let's get down to the nub of this.

Essence

SYNONYMS
quintessence, soul, spirit, ethos, nature, life, lifeblood, core, heart, centre, crux, nub, nucleus, kernel, marrow, meat, pith, gist, substance, principle, central part, fundamental quality, basic quality, essential part, intrinsic nature, sum and substance, reality, actuality

informal nitty-gritty

Answer (score -1):

[Amalgamate?](https://www.google.com/search?q=amalgamate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=2wRrWPj6KtDZ8gek1Z2wDQ)

> to combine or unite to form one organization or structure

Comment: Answer would be stronger (and over 10 characters) with a definition and citation.

Comment: I added definition and citation, but this is usually expected from the poster...